# Three.js - How to group together multiple imported models

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm attempting to reduce the amount of drawcalls in my THREE.js scene. I have a large 32x32 of tiles that are .gtlf models imported from disk. Some grid tiles get a model (that has just 8 vertices and a texture). However, inspecting this canvas with a third part tool like Spector shows that there's 151 draw calls, and it seems  like every model is being drawn separately.

They are created by looping through the grid for every tile, seeing if that tile needs a model, if so, it gets the model data from a Map where it was loaded with the THREE.GLTFLoader. Sometimes, but rarely, the material changes and so may the rotation, but only during setup.

These tiles will never need to be moved or have their transforms changed. They will be static. Is there some sort of optimisation I can perform to group the rendering of these tiles into as few drawcalls as possible, seeing as they are in essence the same object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge your tiles into one geometry.

Something along the lines of this

```
const mergedGeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry()
tiles.forEach( tile=>{
  const geom = tile.geometry.clone()
  geom.applyMatrix(tile.matrixWorld)
  mergedGeom.merge(geom)
}
```

If you do have many different materials and textures you will somehow have to manage that though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and sorry fro the delay in getting back to you! I tried this and it seems like all the tiles merge at the centre of the world. They've had their positions set before I call `geo.applyMatrix()` so I'm not sure why this is an issue. I also tried to call `tile.updateMatrix();` before I apply the matrix, which didn't change anything.

Comment: Nevermind! I forgot that the tiles were part of a `THREE.Group` so I applied their own matrixWorld and then the groups matrix to the geometry. Now they're fine.

Comment: @davidpox: Can you please put your solution here so that this will help others